# Global imports in inheritance?

Tags: python, import, module

Imagine a module called `base` with a class called `Base` in it.
Now inside an other module, called `sub`, inherit a class `Sub` from `Base`:

```
import base
class Sub(base.Base):
    pass
```

Now what if we add a third class, that inherits from `Sub` and takes a parameter that has to be type of `Base` or one of it's subclasses:

```
import sub
class Deep(sub.Sub):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        if isinstance(parent, sub.base.Base):
            pass
```

Going deeper and deeper down in the inheritance tree, the path to `Base` will become `thedeepest.deeperanddeeper.reallydeep.deep.sub.base.Base`, which nobody would like.

I could of course just do `from base import *` and `from sub import *` and then just use `Base`, but is there a way to import so that I can use the prefix of ONLY the original module of my class?

For example:

```
import deep
class ReallyDeep(deep.Deep):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # I know my polymorphism, this is just an example.
        if isinstance(parent, sub.Sub):
            pass
        elif isinstance(parent, base.Base):
            pass
```

Comment: Why access `Base` through a chain of modules defining subclasses of `Base`, rather than immediately through `base`? Apart from that, no inheritance hierarchy should be deeper than a couple of classes. (Whether "couple" means 2 or up to 5 here is up to you; I lean towards 2.)

Comment: @delnan `base` is already imported in the submodules, why import it again? Unless python has a built-in `#ifndef`, in which case this question is useless. Inheritance tree should be two to five classes deep, and rather two? OS X (and all the large projects) must've been coded badly... https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/efa73ee50d8edfd0e1d4294cf4bd2c07d9f8af77/documentation/html/MacOS/inherits.html

Comment: Modules are indeed never imported twice. Perhaps you should re-read the tutorial. RE inheritance depth: The specific number is both a rule of thumb and an absolute, and Python-specific (quite often, you should have zero classes where you would have one class in another language). A related principle (favor composition over inheritance) holds in all OO languages though, and is indeed sometimes disregarded. Being large doesn't make a code base good.

Comment: @delnan Thank you for *"Modules are indeed never imported twice."*. I'm just gonna ignore the rest of your comment cause you seem to have no idea what you're talking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules in Python are like singletons, they only get imported once, so

```
import base
import deep
class ReallyDeep(deep.Deep):
    def __init__(self, parent):
       if isinstance(parent, base.Base):
           pass
```

Is absolutely no problem at all, in fact, it's the best way to do it.

What delnan means is that in most cases deeply nested inheritance trees are a sign of bad design. As with any rule, there are exceptions. But in general avoiding deeply nested trees will make your code more understandable, easier to test and therefore easier to maintain.

Comment: This would be a perfect answer if you didn't start thrash talking about the depth of inheritance. You're both wrong about it, and it was not my question.